# Flask: how to render view + add to database based on URL request path

Tags: python, flask

I'm making a webapp with flask and SQL.

What I'm trying to do I can't seem to find the correct search terminology for:

- I have my homepage at myapp/
- I want to make it so when users add whatever path (myapp/whatever; myapp/hello) they will be rendered a certain view/blueprint (not redirected) and the name of the path ('whatever', 'hello') will be newly added to my database (unless someone has already opened it before)

I am sure this is a very common thing to do but I just cannot seem to find maybe the correct way to phrase it for google. I kind of found something about request.path which will give me the 'whatever'/'hello' part but I can't figure out how to piece the rest together.

Therefore, if someone could please either direct me with what to search, or if you know how to do it or have any resources, I will be very grateful. Thank you :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand what you're looking for is a route that accepts a [keyword argument](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#variable-rules), creates a record in the database, and returns a template.

```
@app.route('/<path_name>')
def save_path():

    # Do database insert here

    return render_template('mytemplate.html')
```